# Animation Nodes - Object ID keys - Additional influence for a selected objects?

Tags: animation-nodes

again,

I am still battling with Object ID keys (OIk). And this time I am trying to mask out or add an additional motion to the selected group of bojects from an already animated matrix.
I am using OIk because I need to have precise states in matrices.

So my attempt was as shown in an image bellow. To create a group of objects and offset their position along +x axis with a help of a driver. But In addition I need part of that group to be offset in different direction (-x for example).

(Object controlled falloff) node with several object inputs does not suite me in this case, because I need a specific few from that group to have an additional or different kind of offset. And falloff will bleed its effect on an undesired cubes.

This setup that I did kinda work, but kinda don't some of the cubes loose their positions other don't react at all..

I tried to use second loop, but it cuts of the part of the matrix permanently And I cannot influence it with previous drivers anymore.

Again, I hope my explanation at least some what understandble..[image]

p.s. I'm using a 2.79b

Comment: I am sorry I haven't answered your questions. I have been very busy the last couple of days. Will answer it as soon as I get the time, I promise.

Comment: No problem, You've been a great help. So I'll just sit and wait quietly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem? Maybe give a simple example. As I can't understand the problem right now.

Comment: Example: I have wavy, wiggling and in some other way moving cubesin one axis. At some point I need a set of 9 cubes (that form a square) stop at set height. After some time another set of 12 or similar cubes. The grid can be 10x10 or it can be 100x40. Also going to that height cubes need to gradually  change color (this one I solved using vertex color sets) .. For now I've got suggestion from colleagues to try using animated textures and displacement. But I'm afraid, I may loose color control. I tried using separate groups chosen from the original matrix, but they have different index numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the objects to stop at a certain height that may be computed as an offset of the object's location, simply overwrite the used falloff by taking the maximum or the minimum of it with a custom falloff that represents the state of the object. Here is an example:

[image: Example 1]

This offsets the matrices by the maximum amount if their x location is larger than 2.